# Change url of nodes in the past - Pathauto; Date module

Tags: datetime, path-aliases

I have a content type that includes the date module as a field type. Some of these nodes have the date set in the past and some in the future.

[image: All drupal nodes]

I have been able to have only the nodes that have the date set in the past to appear in a view

[image: View filter criteria]

[image: Nodes set in the past]

What I'd like is for these nodes to have a different url set to the other nodes in the same content type.
For instance Pathauto may assign these nodes a url of

**www.example.com/node-1**

Once this node's date is in the past I'd like it to automatically appear at something like

**www.example.com/past-nodes/node-1**

The previous url **/node-1** would redirect to the new **/past-nodes/node-1** url.

Where **www.example.com/past-nodes/** would be the view of past nodes as in the third image.

The breadcrumb trail should also reflect this e.g. **home >> past-nodes >> node-1**

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: Idea seems neat, but do you really want to invalidate links the very day their content was most interesting? Imagine your user sharing a link on Facebook: "I will be at ... !" and then "I was at ... wait a moment, where is my link!?". Not good. Question is interesting, but the very idea looks a bit dangerous.

Comment: Good point. Here's a bit more context - The nodes will be related to events so they'll have a start and end date. Once the event is over it'll be going into the past events page.

I guess it wouldn't harm to leave the old url but also have the added past-nodes/node-1 url pattern. The old url could redirect to the new url if it is in the past.

The main thing that is annoying me is the breadcrumb trail leads to **home >> current-node** rather than **home >> past-nodes >> current-node**

Comment: And that's a pretty neat solution. Please edit your question to include it as it changes how desired "flow" looks like.